# disable window reposition in VimClojure?

Tags: clojure, vim, vimclojure

I'm using [VimClojure](https://github.com/vim-scripts/VimClojure) plugin. Sometime when I use `o` to insert a new line, the plugin will reposition the window and move the current line to the bottom of window. It's very annoying especially when I've typed `zz` to center the current line.

I've read the [document](https://github.com/vim-scripts/VimClojure/blob/master/doc/clojure.txt) but found nothing related, can someone tell me how to disable this feature?

EDIT: thanks to Ingo Karkat's suggestion, [switching to foreplay.vim](http://clojure-doc.org/articles/tutorials/vim_foreplay.html) will solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use *VimClojure*, but it sounds like a bug in the plugin, not a feature. Probably, some `winsaveview()` / `winrestview()` is missing. I would submit that issue to the author.

Comment: Thanks! I also want to submit an issue but seems they've closed the issue page. While I'm not familiar with vim script & `.vim` directory layout, can you help me locate the file responsible for this bug, I'll attempt to RTFM and fix this if possible.

Comment: I've read that the plugin won't be actively maintained anymore, and people are encouraged to move to a [different plugin](http://clojure-doc.org/articles/tutorials/vim_foreplay.html).